# Form Input label keep transform position

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, email

My problem is simple, im trying to keep the `label` of the email `input` field in its transformed position after user typed in any text and not just `:valid` text/email.

So in the snippet you can see if you as user type in an **valid** email , the label will keep its transformed position, even if you click outside the iput field.

**This is the css that checks for valid input and keeps the transformation, and works as expected**

```
.contact-form .input-text:valid + .label {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 600;
  bottom: 20px;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-24px);
  transform: translateY(-24px);
}
```

**PROBLEM**
- now try typing in just random text in the input field and then click outside the input field you wil see the label go back to its original position.

**Question** - How can i keep the `label` in its transformed position based on any text that is entered in the input field and keep that `label` position if clicked outside the input field.

Was hoping this would work:

```
.contact-form div.email input[type=email] + .label {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 600;
  bottom: 20px;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-24px);
  transform: translateY(-24px);
}
```

**My Code**

```css
div.row {
  padding: 50px;
}

.contact-form .label {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 12px;
    font-size: 30px;
    line-height: 26px;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #ccc;
    cursor: text;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .2s ease-in-out;
    transition: -webkit-transform .2s ease-in-out;
    transition: transform .2s ease-in-out;
    transition: transform .2s ease-in-out, -webkit-transform .2s ease-in-out;
}

.contact-form .input-text {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    padding: 30px 0px;
    border-width: 0 0 1px 0;
    border-color: #ccc;
    font-size: 36px;
    line-height: 26px;
    font-weight: 400;
}

.contact-form .form-field {
    position: relative;
    margin: 16px 0;
    width: 95%;
}

.contact-form .input-text:focus {
    outline: none;
}

.contact-form .input-text:focus + .label {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-24px);
    transform: translateY(-24px);
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 600;
    bottom: 20px;
}

.contact-form .input-text:valid + .label {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 600;
    bottom: 20px;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-24px);
    transform: translateY(-24px);
}
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row extra">
<div class="col-md-6">  
<form class="contact-form row extra">

  <div class="form-field email">
      <input id="email" class="input-text js-input" type="email" required>
  <label class="label" for="email">Your Email</label>
  </div>
  
  <div class="form-field colalign-center submit-form">
      <input class="submit-btn btn btn-custom pull-right" type="submit" value="Send">
  </div>
  
</form>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-fill-mode.asp

Comment: @Gerard can you please help me understand how this wil do?

Comment: please explain the downvotes??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by adding the placeholder to the input and hiding it by opacity and when some enter the text in input by checking if the placeholder is not shown I hold the same position of the label

```css
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
   color: #666;
   opacity: 0;
}

:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
   color: #666;
   opacity: 0;
}

::-moz-placeholder {  /* Firefox 19+ */
   color: #666;
   opacity: 0;
}

:-ms-input-placeholder {
   color: #666;
   opacity: 0;
}

div.row {
  padding: 50px;
}

.contact-form .label {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 12px;
    font-size: 30px;
    line-height: 26px;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #ccc;
    cursor: text;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .2s ease-in-out;
    transition: -webkit-transform .2s ease-in-out;
    transition: transform .2s ease-in-out;
    transition: transform .2s ease-in-out, -webkit-transform .2s ease-in-out;
}

.contact-form .input-text {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    padding: 30px 0px;
    border-width: 0 0 1px 0;
    border-color: #ccc;
    font-size: 36px;
    line-height: 26px;
    font-weight: 400;
}

.contact-form .form-field {
    position: relative;
    margin: 16px 0;
    width: 95%;
}

.contact-form .input-text:focus {
    outline: none;
}

.contact-form .input-text:focus + .label {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-24px);
    transform: translateY(-24px);
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 600;
    bottom: 20px;
}

.contact-form .input-text:not(:placeholder-shown) + label{
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-24px);
    transform: translateY(-24px);
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 600;
    bottom: 20px;
}

.contact-form .input-text:valid + .label {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 600;
    bottom: 20px;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-24px);
    transform: translateY(-24px);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="row extra">
<div class="col-md-6">  
<form class="contact-form row extra">

  <div class="form-field email">
      <input id="email" class="input-text js-input" type="email" placeholder="email" required>
  <label class="label" for="email">Your Email</label>
  </div>
  
  <div class="form-field colalign-center submit-form">
      <input class="submit-btn btn btn-custom pull-right" type="submit" value="Send">
  </div>
  
</form>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice i like this approach , thanks man, stil dont get all the downvotes, maybe they just know how to solve the issue!

Comment: so i eneded up just giving placeholder an empty space, `placeholder=" "` and then used your css tip thanks `.contact-form .input-text:not(:placeholder-shown) + .label`

Comment: glad that help you :)